# xdm server on Pi

Tags: xorg, remote

Has anyone tried to setup xdm server (or any variant of this service) on Raspberry Pi?
Assuming, I have setup 'command line' version of raspberry pi installed without connecting Pi to any screen or keyboard.
I would like to access Pi through X / xdmcp.
What is the minimal setup?

Comment: Are you just talking about a simple `ssh` connection, with the display forwarded to your PC, or something else?

Comment: I'm talking about daemon like xdm, with capability to listen for incoming connections like XDMCP. Finally, I would like to use my tool Xming to connect to Pi, and have login screen and full graphical environment ready to work.

Comment: The answer came after a few weeks. Look at http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=21246

Comment: Also note that xdm can forward.  This mean that xdm does not have to run on the destination host, but can run elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably more suitable as a comment, but have you seen [this tutorial](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/pixming.php)?  I was able to use these instructions on my system without problem.

As is [mentioned here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToCygwinX) for a different Linux flavor, XDMCP is inherently insecure and you are advised to use it only behind a firewall.

Comment: The link does not say _why_ it is inherently insecure.